# React Material UI Drawer - Warning Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a React MUI Drawer and although I have given key prop to child in the List still getting this warning message when the react mui drawer opens. I have attached some screen shots and sample code that I have written.

[image: Overview Layout]

[image: Warning after Drawer Opens]

**AppBarWithDrawer Component**

```
import React from "react";
// Components
import { Box, AppBar, Toolbar } from "material-ui";
import DrawerMenu from "../navbar/drawerMenu";

export default function appBarWithDrawer() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <DrawerMenu />
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

**DrawerMenu Component**

```
import React from 'react';
// Components
import { Button, Box, Drawer } from 'material-ui';
import CustomIcon from 'material-ui-icons';
import DrawerMenuList from './drawerMenuList';
// Constants 
import { MENU_ICON } from 'material-ui-icon-types/iconTypes';
import { DASHBOARD_MENU_ICON_THEME } from 'material-ui-icon-types/themeTypes';

export default function DrawerMenu () {

    // Drawer menu type
    const LEFT_MENU_TYPE = 'left';

    const Icon = ({ iconType }) => {
        return (<CustomIcon icon={iconType} theme={DASHBOARD_MENU_ICON_THEME} />);
    };

    // Left Drawer Menu status
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        left: false
    });

    const toggleDrawer = (anchor) => (event) => {
        if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
            return;
        }
        setState({ ...state, [anchor]: !state.left });
    };

    const list = (anchor) => (
        <Box
            sx={{ width: 240 }}
            role="presentation"
            onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor)}
            onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor)}
        >
            <DrawerMenuList />
        </Box>
    );


    return (
            <div>
                <Button className="navHamburgerButton" onClick={toggleDrawer(LEFT_MENU_TYPE)}> 
                   <Icon iconType={MENU_ICON} />
                </Button>
                <Drawer
                    anchor={LEFT_MENU_TYPE}
                    open={state[LEFT_MENU_TYPE]}
                    onClose={toggleDrawer(LEFT_MENU_TYPE)}
                >
                    {list(LEFT_MENU_TYPE)}
                </Drawer>
            </div>
    );
}
```

I have included the key prop in the each child in a list of the below component as shown but still getting the warninig.

**DrawerMenuList Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Divider, ListItem, ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from 'material-ui';
import CustomIcon from 'material-ui-icons';
import {
    SCHOOL_OUTLINED_ICON, SPEED_OUTLINED_ICON, FORMAT_LIST_NUMBERED_RTL_ICON,
    CREATE_OUTLINED_ICON
} from 'material-ui-icon-types/iconTypes';
import { DASHBOARD_MENU_ICON_THEME } from 'material-ui-icon-types/themeTypes';

export default function DrawerMenuList () {

    // Reusable icon for the Drawer List. The "DASHBOARD_MENU_ICON_THEME" theme is applied.
    const Icon = ({ iconType }) => {
        return (<CustomIcon icon={iconType} theme={DASHBOARD_MENU_ICON_THEME} />);
    };

    const drawerItems = [
        {
            id: Math.random(),
            name: 'Dashboard',
            icon: SPEED_OUTLINED_ICON
        },
        {
            id: Math.random(),
            name: 'Syllabus',
            icon: FORMAT_LIST_NUMBERED_RTL_ICON
        },
        {
            id: Math.random(),
            name: 'Notes & Highlights',
            icon: CREATE_OUTLINED_ICON
        },
        {
            id: Math.random(),
            name: 'Virtusal Classroom',
            icon: SCHOOL_OUTLINED_ICON

        }
    ];

    return (
            <List>
                {drawerItems.map((item) => (
                    <ListItem button key={item.id}>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <Icon iconType={item.icon} />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
    );
}
```

When I debug in the browser the error fires when executing the below section

[image: Warning Fires when executing these lines]

Comment: I am getting the same warning after using the mui `ListItem` even though I pass a unique `key`. Apparently it needs to be fixed by the library developers.

Answer (score 2):

This error is because you are not giving a key to the child as it should.
I had this same error, I found the solution in the examples of MUI.
I will leave you the link for the [documentation](https://mui.com/api/drawer/) and [examples](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#swipeable-edge)

[image: This is the image of the example from MUI]
In this picture you can see that the anchor is set in a Fragment that is covering the whole button and drawer.

From this:

```
return (
        <List>
            {drawerItems.map((item) => (
                <ListItem button key={item.id}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        <Icon iconType={item.icon} />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
                </ListItem>
            ))}
        </List>
);
```

You can try This:

```
return (
   <List>
       {drawerItems.map((item) => (
        <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
           <ListItem button>
               <ListItemIcon>
                   <Icon iconType={item.icon} />
               </ListItemIcon>
               <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
           </ListItem>
         </React.Fragment>
       ))}
   </List>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your code should work as you are assigning key. You could try this code once.

```
<List>
   {drawerItems.map((item, index) => (
      <ListItem button key={index}>
         ...
      </ListItem>
   ))}
</List>
```